# Cannot connect to a dockerized Express.js app from another docker container

Tags: docker, express

I have two containers App and Webserver. Webserver is plain nginx:alpine image and App is expressjs app running on port 3030 under ubuntu:focal. I heard that this is a common practise to use  separate containers for application and server. So I added `proxy_pass http://app:3030/;` to nginx config. Something went wrong and I digged into this a bit. To exclude incorrect nginx setup I checked raw curl requests from webserver to app container with no luck. Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - ${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80
      - ${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_DIR}
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/ssl/
    depends_on:
      - app
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX}-webserver
    networks:
      - app-network

  app:
    env_file: .env
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
      args:
        APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
        APP_DIR: ${APP_DIR}
        PRODUCT_ID: ${PRODUCT_ID}
      context: ../
    environment:
      - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME_PREFIX}-app
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I can request express from App container CLI:

```
/ # curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:3030/multichannel/4034?uid=a6O5iTje8sR2PESbWpAM
{"status": "OK"}
```

And now from Webserver:

```
/ # ping app
PING app (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
/ # curl -X GET http://172.19.0.2:3030/multichannel/4034?uid=a6O5iTje8sR2PESbWpAM
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.19.0.2 port 3030 after 0 ms: Connection refused
/ # curl -X GET http://app:3030/multichannel/4034?uid=a6O5iTje8sR2PESbWpAM
curl: (7) Failed to connect to app port 3030 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Nginx log (don't pay attention on IP it is correct, after containers were rebuilt it changed):

```
2021/10/29 15:40:46 [error] 24#24: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: api.test, request: "GET /multichannel/4034?uid=a6O5iTje8sR2PESbWpAM HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.20.0.3:3030/multichannel/4034?uid=a6O5iTje8sR2PESbWpAM", host: "api.test"
```

Of course Nginx conf has:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:3030;
    }
```

Why was connection refused? Both containers are in the same network

Comment: @RobertMikes added conf, I think you answer regarding this line `proxy_pass http://app:3030;`

Comment: Hello there! can you please try and remove the specific network section? meaning for each service and at the end of the compose file. also, please after running `docker compose up` or similar please add the output for `docker ps` command

Comment: I think that's not I docker issue but express.js.  What's give app logs ?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque you are right, localhost as host is that kind of things you won't notice at the first glance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the reason why I can't get connected. When @devatherock mentioned `ARTIFACTORY_URL=http://localhost:8081` I checked app code on what host is used and found this:

```
server.listen(3030, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  logger.debug(`Server is running on ${serverConfig.port} port`);
});
```

Then I tried "localhost" as host and still got 502. So it is a time to read the docs. Expressjs `server.listen` works like nodejs `server.listen` https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlistenport-host-backlog-callback

> If host is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.
> In most operating systems, listening to the unspecified IPv6 address (::) may cause the net.Server to also listen on the unspecified IPv4 address (0.0.0.0).

And the answer is to use '0.0.0.0' or just omit host parameter. 127.0.0.1 or localhost accessible only on the local machine because is bounded to the loopback interface.

Answer (score 2):

You need to at least expose the 3030 port on the app container to make it available to other containers:

```
  app:
    expose:
      - "3030"
```

See [the expose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose).

Alternatively, you could [publish the port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports): either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (a random host port will be chosen):

```
  app:
    ports:
      - "3030"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both but it didn't help. Still the same in logs. I read some articles, expose option is only to tell another developers that container uses a port. Publishing port to a host machine for internal services is not a good practice. Also I had 3rd container "websocket" where nodejs uses websocket server and 3000 port and everything works without any tricky set up.

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't have the express app's code, I tried to simulate the issue with the docker image of another app with a simplified version of the docker-compose file and nginx config. I'm using a ubuntu machine as well. But the call from nginx to the app goes through fine in my case.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
    container_name: test-webserver
    networks:
      - app-network

  app:
    image: devatherock/artifactory-badge:latest
    environment:
      - ARTIFACTORY_URL=http://localhost:8081
      - ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY=dummy
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true
    container_name: test-app
    networks:
      - app-network
      
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
events {
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Even I had the same assumption as Robert, that we need to specify the `ports` section for the `app` service, but the call from nginx to app worked even without it. When I hit the endpoint `http://localhost:8081/health` on nginx, it forwards the request to the app at `http://app:8080/health` and returns the response `{"status":"UP"}` that the app's health check returns